# If $U_1, U_2, U_3$, are iid Uniform $[0,1]$ in ascending order, what is the pdf of $U_1, U_3$ and the joint pdf of $U_1, U_3$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

[image]

I am really stuck with this questions as I have no idea how to form a pdf for any of them since they are all dependent on each other

I have tried to create a joint pdf of all 3 and then integrated out the other 2 to get the marginal pdf of one of them but it does not really seem to be working.

Comment: I don't think that there's any way of solving this that's better than simply doing the combinatorics. Let's find the distribution function of $X_3$ for instance: What needs to happen in order to get $X_3\leq t$?

Comment: The key word is this: [order statistic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic)

Answer (score 0):

Let $X_1 = \min(U_1,U_2,U_3)$ then
\begin{align}
\Pr(X_1 \leq x ) &= 1 - \Pr(X_1 > x) \\
&= 1 - \prod_{i=1}^3 \Pr(U_i > x) \\
&= 1 - [\Pr(U >x)]^3\\
&= 1 - [1 - \Pr(U \leq x)]^3\\
&= 1 - [1 - x]^3\\
\end{align}
The above is the CDF so the PDF should be 
$$f_{X_1}(x) = \frac{d}{dx} \Pr(X_1 \leq x ) = 3(1-x)^2$$
You could proceed as such.

Comment: Ohh I see what you mean. Thanks for the help! Thats what I needed to get started